# Flutter List Behaviour is not as expected

Tags: list, flutter, dart

I am making a filtering system in flutter by using two lists called `mailList` and `filteredMailList`. The first time `mailList` is populated, this code runs:

```
setState(() {
  filteredMailList.clear();
  filteredMailList = mailList;
});
```

When this has been done, it seems as though any changes that I make on `mailList` get replicated to filteredMailList even though I haven't executed those two lines again. For example:

```
//Assume that mailList = ["1", "2", "3"] and filteredMailList = []
filteredMailList = mailList
//I expect then mailList = ["1", "2", "3"] and filteredMailList = ["1", "2", "3"]
mailList.add("4")
//I expect then mailList = ["1", "2", "3", "4"] and filteredMailList = ["1", "2", "3"]
//However when this is run mailList = ["1", "2", "3", "4"] and filteredMailList = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
```

Does this have something to do with the fact that I might not be giving both lists the same contents, but instead saying that they are referencing the same list?

Is there a way to make `filteredMailList` only contain the elements of `mailList` and not actually reference the exact same list, so each one can still be edited independently?

Comment: you have to use a copy of `mailList` instead of `filteredMailList = mailList` - see available `List` constructors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your code by calling `filteredMailList = mailList;` you are actually removing your original filteredMailList List (you don't have any refrence to that list anymore) and changing it to the mailList. so both filteredMailList and mailList points to a single List in memory

you can create a clone list from mailList like :

```dart
filteredMailList = [...mailList]; // or filteredMailList = mailList.toList();
```

or keep your original refrence and copy all items from mailList

```dart
filteredMailList.clear();
filteredMailList.addAll(mailList);
```